# Decryption of an arbitrary chosen element from a vector of encrypted items causes invalid PKCS #7 block error

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I am trying to encrypt some sequential data using AES in Crypto++. However, I noticed that randomly choosing an encrypted item and decrypt it causes a **StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found**

A simple code that causes the same problem is the following:

```
AESUtil aes;
std::vector<std::string> t = std::vector<std::string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::string p = "a";
    auto c = aes.encrypt(p);
    t.push_back(c);
}

auto d = aes.decrypt(t[78]);
```

where AESUtil is as follow:

```
AESUtil::AESUtil() {
    this->key = CryptoPP::SecByteBlock(0x00, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

    // Generate a random IV
    this->iv = CryptoPP::SecByteBlock(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());

    this->aesEncryption = CryptoPP::AES::Encryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    this->cbcEncryption = CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    this->aesDecryption = CryptoPP::AES::Decryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    this->cbcDecryption = CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption(aesDecryption, iv);
}

void AESUtil::encrypt(std::string &ciphertext, std::string &plaintext) {
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(this->cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.size());
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
}

void AESUtil::decrypt(std::string &plaintext, std::string &ciphertext) {
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(this->cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(plaintext));
    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( ciphertext.c_str()), ciphertext.size());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
}

std::string AESUtil::encrypt(std::string plaintext) {
    std::string ciphertext;
    //ciphertext.reserve(plaintext.size()+16);
    encrypt(ciphertext, plaintext);
    return ciphertext;
}

std::string AESUtil::decrypt(std::string ciphertext) {
    std::string plaintext;
    //plaintext.reserve(ciphertext.size()+16);
    decrypt(plaintext, ciphertext);
    return plaintext;
}
```

I thought the problem was linked to \0 null terminating character in strings, so I changed the code to use hex (not sure it is actually correct). However, the issue persists.

```
void AESUtil::encrypt(std::string &ciphertext, std::string &plaintext) {
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue encrypted;
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter f1(this->cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::Redirector(encrypted));

    //f1.PutWord32((uint32_t)v1.size(), BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
    f1.Put((const unsigned char *) plaintext.c_str(), plaintext.size());
    f1.MessageEnd();
    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
    encrypted.CopyTo(encoder);
    encoder.MessageEnd();
}

void AESUtil::decrypt(std::string &plaintext, std::string &ciphertext) {
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue decrypted;
    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder(new CryptoPP::Redirector(decrypted));
    decoder.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( ciphertext.data()), ciphertext.size());
    decoder.MessageEnd();

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter f2(this->cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(plaintext));
    decrypted.CopyTo(f2);
    f2.MessageEnd();
}
```

With the following code, both the AESUtil versions work without any problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::string p = "a";
        auto c = aes.encrypt(p);
        auto d = aes.decrypt(c);
    }
```

Any idea what is the problem and how I could solve it? Any help would be **very appreciated**

Comment: I would not expect a utility class to contain state or even that it can be instantiated, nor would I expect a decrypter to have an encrypter inside or vice versa. That class design leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I am aware the class design is not ideal. Being in an early stage in development I was solely interested in its practical use. Having everything in a class and making it as simple as possible was the faster approach. Anyway, thank you for your suggestions, I will certainly make use of them when refactoring.

Comment: Note that the IV / key combination should always be unique, otherwise your cipher is about as secure as ECB mode, immediately leaking information about identical blocks at the start of the plaintext. Usually you store the IV with the ciphertext instead. If you run into problems like this: print out the hexadecimal representation of the key, IV and input / output *for both encryption and decryption* to check what is amiss. Usually it is some intermediate encoding error or (for C / C++) some mistake in taking the size of a binary string.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I tried what you suggested and everything seems to be fine. Key and IV do not change between operations and the size of the ciphertext is always the same (the same for the hex values). I have noted that if I decrypt the vector in the same order the elements are put in, the decryption succeeds for all the elements. Could it be because of the state?

Comment: I'll try storing the IV with the ciphertext and see if it changes something.

Comment: That could well be the case because you save the instantiations of the object. Generally you should just construct them where required and only keep a reference to the key. Setting up the cipher means deriving the sub-key but that's not a very computation intensive operation - the rest of the state is just a few buffering bytes and the last ciphertext block - nothing to speak of really.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I have changed the code to store the IV with the ciphertext. Everything works perfectly now. Thank you very much. I'll further improve the code with all the other suggestions you gave me. Thanks again.

Comment: Crypto libraries react differently when cipher instances they are reused (some don't even allow reuse, which might just be the best option). You might want to answer your question yourself and indicate that the IV has changed even if `MessageEnd` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The IV was changing even if `MessageEnd` was called, **keeping a reference to the state** of AESUtil.

I solved the problem by randomly generating the IV during the encryption process and storing it together with the ciphertext.

If anyone is interested, here is the new code:

```
void AESUtil::encrypt(std::string &ciphertext, std::string &plaintext) {
    // Generate a random IV
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    this->rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());
    //memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

    CryptoPP::StringSink stringSink(ciphertext);

    CryptoPP::ArraySource as(iv, iv.size(), true,
                             new CryptoPP::Redirector(stringSink));

    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(this->aesEncryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::ByteQueue encrypted;
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter f1(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::Redirector(encrypted));

    f1.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.size());
    f1.MessageEnd();

    CryptoPP::HexEncoder encoder(new CryptoPP::Redirector(stringSink));
    encrypted.CopyTo(encoder);
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    std::string recovered;
    CryptoPP::StringSink sink(recovered);
    encrypted.CopyTo(sink);
}

void AESUtil::decrypt(std::string &plaintext, std::string &ciphertext) {
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(ciphertext, false /* DO NOT Pump All */);

    // Attach new filter
    CryptoPP::ArraySink as(iv, iv.size());
    ss.Attach(new CryptoPP::Redirector(as));
    ss.Pump(CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);  // Pump first 16 bytes

    CryptoPP::StringSink stringSink(plaintext);
    CryptoPP::ByteQueue decrypted;
    CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder(new CryptoPP::Redirector(decrypted));

    ss.Detach(new CryptoPP::Redirector(decoder));
    ss.PumpAll();

    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(this->aesDecryption, iv);
    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter f2(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::Redirector(stringSink));
    decrypted.CopyTo(f2);
    f2.MessageEnd();
}
```